# Returning 2 values from onCreate() cloud function in Firestore?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to create the following two documents in different nodes from a cloud function, but not sure how to return both.

```js
// Listen to .onCreate trigger
exports.createUserAndProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

  // Create a new user (only the user themselves can access this)
  const newUser = admin.firestore().doc(`/users/${user.uid}`).set({
    announcements: [],
    email: user.email,
    onboardingSteps: ["setName", "syncStuff"],
  });

  // Create the user's public profile (any user can access this)
  const newPublicProfile = admin.firestore().doc(`/profiles/${user.uid}`).set({
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    preferredName: null,
  });

  return newUser;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both writes to complete before terminating the Cloud Function, you can return them in a `Promise.all()` call:

```
return Promise.all(newUser, newPublicProfile);
```

Also see the MDN documentation for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).